# Axios and fetch both in Reactjs are making continuous localhost network request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

This is the route code form express backend and MongoDB database and normal call from frontend with `fetch("/")` it was returning index.html code and on adding `fetch("http://localhost:9000")` it was returning CORS Error so I added `app.use(cors())`.

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  Journal.find({}, function (err, journals) {
    if (err) {
      res.send("Something went wrong");
    }
    res.json(journals);
  });
});
```

This is the axios and fetch request made from reactjs frontend, on making fetch and axios call on "/" as at the backend nothing was coming up only index.html code was being returned so therefore I started using "http://localhost:9000" then data was coming but this localhost problem came up.

```
const [journals, setJournals] = useState([
    { title: "Day 1", content: content_string },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getJournalData();
  });

  // const getJournalData = async () => {
  //   try {
  //     const res = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/");

  //     const data = await res.json();

  //     setJournals(data);
  //     console.log(data);
  //   } catch (err) {
  //     console.error(err);
  //   }
  // };

  const getJournalData = () => {

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:9000/")
      .then((res) => {
        setJournals(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

This is chrome-dev-tools network tab:

[image: Chrome-dev-tools network tab]

Console Content

[image: Console Content]

React is working at localhost:3000
Express is working on locahost:9000

proxy:http://localhost:9000 is added in package.json in frontend react app

Please tell me what is goind and how can I fix it.
Thankyou

Comment: u should add [] to useEffect as second parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using an array of dependencies, every change will trigger your `useEffect` to run again.

So every re-render, every changing state will cause you to create another Api calls.

Let's talk about variant useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // invoking on every re-render
})

useEffect(() => {
  // invoking on component did mount (once)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  // invoking on component did mount and with every change on counter
}, [counter])
```

So, change your code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getJournalData();
  }, []);
```